# How to download or fetch the URL of various versions of a file present in S3 bucket?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am able to fetch all the versions of a file present in a version enabled S3 bucket, but the download url that is generated downloads only the latest version. So how can i download all the versions of a file using Java?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using [ListVersionsRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ListVersionsRequest.html) and [VersionListing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/VersionListing.html)

First create request,

```
ListVersionsRequest request = new ListVersionsRequest()
                .withBucketName(bucketName)
                .withMaxResults(2);
```

Now you can call [listVersions()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#listVersions-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListVersionsRequest-) using your AmazonS3 client, this will return `VersionListing` as response.

```
versionListing = s3client.listVersions(request);
```

As [documentation states](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/VersionListing.html#isTruncated--), `isTruncated()` on `versionListing` will return `true` if the version listing is not complete, which indicates that additional calls to AWS S3 are needed to obtain complete version listing results.

In addition response will contain next key maker, which you can set to the request and loop until `isTruncated()` is `false`.

Here is a full [code example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/list-obj-version-enabled-bucket.html) from AWS